# What is a shadow program committee?

Tags: conference, peer-review, program-committee

I recently stumbled over the term “**shadow program committee**”, e.g. [here](http://eurosys2015.labri.fr/calls/shadow/).

What is a shadow program  committee? Why is it put in place, and when? What is its relation to the normal PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link that you provide explains it fairly clearly for that academic community. They have chosen to organize training in reviewing and conference organization by setting up a group that does the same work as the real program committee.  The shadow group's work, however, is done only for training purposes and does not affect the actual decisions on papers.  This is similar to a [mock trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_trial) or [moot court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moot_court) in the legal arena: a chance to do "the real thing" without doing real damage if one screws up.  It both gives practice and helps the main organizers identify people who are ready to be brought onto the real program committee.

This is not a widespread mechanism in the scientific, however, so other communities may not mean the same thing if they use the same words.

Comment: Thanks. I found it hard to believe that they go trough all that trouble (e.g. travelling across Europe) if it is all just a mock and moot, and the result is not even used to cross-validate the real PC’s decisions.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I don't disagree---I would think it would make more sense to hold the meeting as a workshop the day before the conference instead.  Then again, my communities don't generally ask the real PC to turn up in person either, but I was once invited to a PC where they got really miffy when I didn't want to fly across the country to California to help make decision.  Some communities have smaller PCs and put a lot more burden on them---notice that they are also asked to review 15-20 papers each!